# How to flatten the nested JSON file in order to retrieve an expected fields

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
[ 
  {'docType': 'custom',
   'fields': 
    {
      'general_info': None,
      'power': 20,
      'safety': 
       {
         'boundingBox': [2.375,9.9,4.98,9.9,4.98,10.245,2.375,10.245],
         'confidence': 0.69,
         'page': 22,
         'text': 'bla-bla-bla',
         'type': 'string',
         'valueString': 'bla-bla-bla'
       },
       'replacement': 
        {
          'boundingBox': [2.505,2.51,2.54,2.51,2.54,3.425,2.505,3.425],
          'confidence': 0.262,
          'page': 7,
          'text': 'bla-bla-bla',
          'type': 'string',
          'valueString': 'bla-bla-bla'
         },
        'document_id': 'x123'
     } 
   }
]
```

I want to go through all `field` values and extract `text` from nested fields. The expected results is as the follows:

```
{
   'labels': 
    {
       'general_info': None,
       'power': 20,
       'safety': 'bla-bla-bla',
       'replacement': 'bla-bla-bla',
       'document_id': 'x123'
     } 
}
```

How can I flatted my JSON file and get an expected result?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import json

json_object = json.load(raw_json)

fields = {}
for field in json_object:
    for attribute, value in field.items():
        fields[attribute] = value

fields_json = json.dumps(fields, indent = 4)
```

However, I don't know how to recursively enter into nested fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After load it as python list just loop over it to get inside `dict` key called `fields` and simply loop on its `keys` and `values` once you found `value` whose type is `dict` you have to loop on it to and get the inside value whose `key` is `text` then get value only and the `key` be parent `key`

### Example

```
from pprint import pprint

res = {}
for sub in content:
   for x, y in sub['fields'].items():
    if isinstance(y, dict):
        for i, e in y.items():
            if i == 'text':
                res[x] = e
    else:
        res[x] = y

final = {}
final['label'] = res
pprint(final)
```

### output

```
{'label': {'document_id': 'x123',
           'general_info': None,
           'power': 20,
           'replacement': 'bla-bla-bla',
           'safety': 'bla-bla-bla'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursive function. It should call itself when a value is a dictionary.

This is an example.

```
def flatten_fields(d):
    out = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            out[k] = flatten_fields(v)
        elif k == 'text':
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            continue
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out
```

To run it, you can iterate through each dictionary in the `json_object`.  You only have one example above, but this is the how:

```
labels = []
for d in json_object:
    labels.append({'labels': flatten_fields(d.get('fields', {}))})

labels
# returns:
[{'labels': {'general_info': None,
   'power': 20,
   'safety': 'bla-bla-bla',
   'replacement': 'bla-bla-bla',
   'document_id': 'x123'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use recursion to walk through dictionary.
My solution would be:

```
import json
with open('raw_json', 'r') as j:
    d = json.load(j)
    # print(d)

def dict_walker(obj ,key=None):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in obj:
            dict_walker(obj[key], key)
    else:
        print(key, ':', obj)

dict_walker(d)
```

OUT:

```
docType : custom
general_info : None
power : 20
boundingBox : [2.375, 9.9, 4.98, 9.9, 4.98, 10.245, 2.375, 10.245]
confidence : 0.69
page : 22
text : bla-bla-bla
type : string
valueString : bla-bla-bla
boundingBox : [2.505, 2.51, 2.54, 2.51, 2.54, 3.425, 2.505, 3.425]
confidence : 0.262
page : 7
text : bla-bla-bla
type : string
valueString : bla-bla-bla
document_id : x123
```